# Searching through a list of lists and displaying results

Tags: python, list, tabular

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
[['De Aza, Alejandro', 'CWS', '153', '607', '84', '160', '27', '4', '17'],
 ['Hunter, Torii', 'DET', '144', '606', '90', '184', '37', '5', '17'],
 ['Hamilton, Josh', 'LAA', '151', '576', '73', '144', '32', '5', '21'],
 ['Choo, Shin-Soo', 'CIN', '154', '569', '107', '162', '34', '2', '21'],
 ['Upton, Justin', 'ATL', '149', '558', '94', '147', '27', '2', '27'],
 ['Cabrera, Miguel', 'DET', '148', '555', '103', '193', '26', '1', '44'],
 ['Posey, Buster', 'SF', '148', '520', '61', '153', '34', '1', '15'],
 ['Suzuki, Ichiro', 'NYY', '150', '520', '57', '136', '15', '3', '7'],
 ['Holliday, Matt', 'STL', '141', '520', '103', '156', '31', '1', '22'],
 ['Headley, Chase', 'SD', '141', '520', '59', '130', '35', '2', '13'],
 ['Cabrera, Asdrubal', 'CLE', '136', '508', '66', '123', '35', '2', '14'],
 ['Pierzynski, A.J.', 'TEX', '134', '503', '48', '137', '24', '1', '17'],
 ['Hoes, L.J.', 'HOU', '46', '167', '24', '48', '7', '2', '1'],
 ['Young Jr., Eric', 'COL', '57', '165', '22', '40', '9', '3', '1'],
 ['Hairston, Scott', 'CHC', '52', '99', '13', '17', '2', '0', '8'],
 ['Arnaud, Travis', 'NYM', '31', '99', '4', '20', '3', '0', '1'],
 ['Ankiel, Rick', 'NYM', '20', '66', '7', '12', '4', '1', '2'],
 ['Ankiel, Rick', 'HOU', '25', '62', '6', '12', '3', '0', '5'],
 ['den Dekker, Matt', 'NYM', '27', '58', '7', '12', '1', '0', '1'],
 ['Sanchez, Angel', 'CWS', '1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

And I want the user to input a command like "TEAM DET" and a list of all lists that have that team element be generated, so "TEAM DET" would come up with something like:

```
Name          | Team | Games played | at bats | runs scored | hits | doubles | triples | homeruns |
Hunter, Torii | DET  | 144          | 606     | 90          | 184  | 37      | 5       | 17       |
```

And so on with all members of DET

EDIT: I'm using python 3.3.3

Comment: List of lists you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify the lookup. Create a dictionary where the team name is the key and all the entries that have that team are the values. So the values will be a list. Hence `defaultdict(list)` would be appropriate.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    data_dict[item[1]].append(item)
pprint(data_dict['DET'])
```

And this would be what you get:

```
[['Hunter, Torii', 'DET', '144', '606', '90', '184', '37', '5', '17'],
 ['Cabrera, Miguel', 'DET', '148', '555', '103', '193', '26', '1', '44']]
```

You can then use the `csv` module to format and display the output the way you need it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tuples, use a list of dictionaries.

Example:

```
players = []
player = {'Player': 'Hunter, Torii', 'Team': 'DET', 'Games Played': '144', 'At Bats': '606', 'Runs Scored': '90', 'Hits': '184', 'Doubles': '37', 'Triples': '5', 'Homeruns': '17']
players.append(player)
#Put each player in that format and append to the list

input = input()

for player in players:
    if player['Team'] == input:
        print(player)
```

Obviously you would format the print statement to look the way you wanted.  If you have any questions just ask below.

Comment: It tells me there is no attribute "append" for a dict

Comment: I have to use elements from a file into this dict

Comment: Oh, so you can't edit the values yourself.  That's fine, might as well use the other answer bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact example program which fullfills your requirement:

```
l=[['De Aza, Alejandro', 'CWS', '153', '607', '84', '160', '27', '4', '17'],
 ['Hunter, Torii', 'DET', '144', '606', '90', '184', '37', '5', '17'],
 ['Hamilton, Josh', 'LAA', '151', '576', '73', '144', '32', '5', '21'],
 ['Choo, Shin-Soo', 'CIN', '154', '569', '107', '162', '34', '2', '21'],
 ['Upton, Justin', 'ATL', '149', '558', '94', '147', '27', '2', '27'],
 ['Cabrera, Miguel', 'DET', '148', '555', '103', '193', '26', '1', '44']]
header="|Name              | Team | Games played | at bats | runs scored | hits | doubles | triples | homeruns |"
formatstring="".join(["|%-"+str(columnwidth)+"s" for columnwidth in [len(i) for i in header.split("|")[1:-1]]])+"|"
command=raw_input("Enter a command!\n")
cmdparts=command.split()
if cmdparts[0]=="TEAM" and len(cmdparts)>=2:
  print header
  for team in cmdparts[1:]:
    for item in l:
      if  team in item[1]:
        print formatstring % tuple(item)
```

When it is called it asks for a command. If you type TEAM DET LAA it will list all entries from the teams DET and LAA in a table:

```
$ python test.py
Enter a command!
TEAM DET LAA
|Name              | Team | Games played | at bats | runs scored | hits | doubles | triples | homeruns |
|Hunter, Torii     |DET   |144           |606      |90           |184   |37       |5        |17        |
|Cabrera, Miguel   |DET   |148           |555      |103          |193   |26       |1        |44        |
|Hamilton, Josh    |LAA   |151           |576      |73           |144   |32       |5        |21        |
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work, if I were using Python 2.x :(

Comment: For Python 3.x you only need to change 4 lines slightly:
`formatstring="".join(["|{:"+str(columnwidth)+"s}" for columnwidth in [len(i) for i in header.split("|")[1:-1]]])+"|"`;
and
`print(header)`;
and
`print(formatstring.format(*tuple(item)))`;
and
`command=input("Enter a command!\n")`